# UITextField __CFStringEncodeByteStream EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, exc-bad-access

I have a strange exception on a UITextField. I solved it but have no clue as to why it does.
After running the application I set the UITextField appearance as follows:

```
UITextField *textfieldAppearance = [UITextField appearance];
textfieldAppearance.font = [_theme textfieldFont];
textfieldAppearance.textColor = [_theme textfieldColor];
if (textDirectionRTL) {
    textfieldAppearance.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
}
textfieldAppearance.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

As you can see, there's nothing unusual about it, but when the controller with the UITextField opens I get a __CFStringEncodeByteStream + 17 EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

[image]

The solution was to comment out the **backgroundColor** setting.
I have the exact same appearance setting on UITextView and everything's ok.
Moreover, when I set the UITextField backgroundColor in the code within awakeAfterUsingCoder, everything works like a charm.
I'm running the app in XCode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503) simulator

Any clue to this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is crashing because you are using the appearance proxy, which doesn't support all customisations. It doesn't seem to support backgroundColor so you will have to modify that on each text field individually

Comment: I'm totally shocked that this powerful feature is so poorly implemented. In fact, I used it on classes which are supposedly not supported and it's working... until it crashes :(. Here's a post with the full list http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/. Thank you

Comment: thanks for the link, good to have a list. i've had the same problem at times and not been sure what will work

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are u using UIAppearance class to customize the UItextfield..?? All the properties u are trying to set are present in UItextField itself...!

```
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:12.0];
```

//Set the properties as you want.

[Refer here for more](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Comment: UIAppearance is a very clean way to set a theme at a single place in the entire application, when it's working... Another option is to create themed classes and inherit them (e.g. ThemedTextField). The downside of this is that I need to use these classes in the Storyboard, which I rather not. It's a bit annoying and easy to forget, especially when a project is developed by many people.